# How to link .so file in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

I have two projects. The output of first one is ***libtest.so*** file. Using this shared object file in the 2nd project, i want to generate final android executable, ***AndroidExe***.

I generated ***libtest.so*** and its ***Android.mk*** is given below

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE :=test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Here the problem i am facing is that, i don't know how to link this ***.so*** file in my final executable project. In this final project, i am using one of the function (sum(a,b)) defined in the .so lib.While do build, showing error undefined reference to 'sum'.Its Android.mk file is given below:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE :=AndroidExe
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libtest.so
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := AndroidExe.c 

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Answer (score 2):

just check [ndk documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and try some of the [samples](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#samples).

Comment: Sorryy...i could not find any sample under ndk directory which explains creating executable . All samples are wriiten for creating libraries.

Comment: My question is how i can call functions defined in an .so file using executable.